# The Taylor series of an interpolated function

Tags: interpolation, series-expansion

I don't have an analytical formula for the function f[x,t] but I have a list of values (table) obtained by applying the inverse of Laplace Transform to the function f[x,s].

How can I apply the Taylor expansion to the following function?

```
g[x,t]= (-1+Sqrt[1+2* k* Interpolation[f[x,t]]])/2*k,
```

where k is a constant.

Comment: It does not sound like a very good idea to me.  Interpolation is polynomial based, so if you work directly with the `InterpolatingFunction`, you can go only up to a certain order (typically 3).  You'd be better off estimating the derivatives directly from the discrete data rather than going through interpolation.  What is your actual goal here?  If you just want a polynomial approximation to a function then something akin to fitting may be better.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do the series first.

Let's suppose that you have the function `expr1={Cos[x]*Sin[t]}`

```
expr2 = Normal[Series[expr1, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]];
A = Table[expr2, {x, 0, 3, 0.5}, {t, 1, 5, 0.5}];
B = Sqrt[1 + 2*k*Interpolation[A]]/2 k - 1
```

with the result:
[image]

or just as you wish

```
Table[Evaluate[{{x, t}, expr1}], {x, 0, 3, 1.}, {t, 0, 3, 1.}];
expr3 = Sqrt[1 + 2*k*%]/2 k - 1;
Series[expr3, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have a formula for f[x,t] to make the series, it is a table of values! and I tried: exper=Series[ F[x,t],{x,o,5}] where F[x,t]  is the table of f[x,t] and it gives the same List of f[x,t]

Comment: @Essam Try FindFit

Comment: then...maybe use the fitting to do the series?

Comment: Before interpolation I got this list:      {{0., 0.0647956}, {0.5, 0.034067}, {1., 0.0173953}, {1.5, 
  0.00873915}, {2., 0.00432485}, {2.5, 0.00210854}, {3., 0.00101385}                                                                                                                           and after interpolation I got the following list        {{0., 0.064587}, {0.488088, 0.0340092}, {0.954451,   0.0173802}, {1.40175, .00873534}},         and when I plotted them on one graph  I got an identical graph (curves). How can I show the very slight difference between these two lists on one graph?

Comment: @Essam Show the difference of them?

Comment: @ tablecircle I plotted the two lists the first list represents a function before interpolation and the second list represents the function after interpolation but both graph are identical. There are no differences in the graphs before or after interpolation. How can i plot two lists of values and show the very slight differences in their corresponding values on their graph?

Comment: @Essam I suggest you can visit [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html). for some options about your figure.
ex. using different scale, range, label,... etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you please check my previous question here in stackexchange: Is it Possible that the list of values and its interpolation function be the same?

Comment: @essam If this answer helps you, you can vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png) or accept it  by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).